# Library names mangled

Tags: cmake

I am trying to link a shared library on Windows using CMake. This shared library was compiled with Clang, and as such I must use GNU ld so that debug symbols get propagated properly (as Microsoft link.exe knows nothing about GNU-style debug symbols). My shared library depends on import libraries for `kernel32.dll` and `msvcrt.dll`. I have the GNU-style import libraries as part of a w32api installation.

However, when I specify the import library names in the `target_link_libraries()` call, the names get mangled so that `target_link_libraries(${my_target} kernel32)` becomes `-lkernel32.lib` on the command line. However, the name for the kernel32 import library is `libkernel32.a`, not `libkernel32.lib.a`, and as such the link is failing. I suspect that this is because my copy of Clang defaults to using Microsoft link.exe, and I set `CMAKE_CXX_CREATE_SHARED_LIBRARY` to override this behavior. If this is the case, I most likely will have to recompile Clang (and hope that I don't get the same behavior in the new copy).

EDIT: Clang is not at fault. I rebuilt Clang from scratch, only to find that the `.lib` suffix is still tacked on automatically. I know it's CMake's fault now. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try modifying the [`CMAKE_LINK_LIBRARY_SUFFIX`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#variable%3aCMAKE_LINK_LIBRARY_SUFFIX) variable:

```
unset(CMAKE_LINK_LIBRARY_SUFFIX)
target_link_libraries(${my_target} kernel32)
```